# Finding equation of tangent to the curve perpendicular to the line

Tags: calculus

I would appreciate some help with the following question:

Find an equation of the tangent line to curve $y=e^{-x}$ which is perpendicular to the line $2x-y=8$

Comment: hint: find the slope of 2x-y=8. Then find the opposite reciprocal of that number. So find y'. Set y'=that number and solve to find for which x ( we will call this number a) it happens. Then your tangent line you seek will be y-f(a)=f'(a)(x-a)

Comment: Thanks randomgirl this was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line $2x-y = 8$ has a slope of $2$.  Any line perpendicular to it must have slope $-\frac{1}{2}$.

The derivative of $y=e^{-x}$ evaluated at a given value of $x$ will give you the slope of the tangent line to to the graph of $y=e^{-x}$ at that value of $x$.  So we wish to solve $\frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{1}{2}$ for $x$, and we thus know that the tangent line at this value of $x$ has slope $-\frac{1}{2}$ as desired.

To finish up, we can write an equation for a line provided we know its slope and a single point through which it passes.  We figured out the desired slope back in the beginning.  How can we find a point that it passes through?  *Draw a picture of what's going on if you're stuck here*.

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite your line: $y = 2x-8$. It has slope $2$, so a line perpendicular to it has slope $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Now what is the question reduced to? It says find and equation of the tangent line to $y=e^{-x}$ with slope $-\frac{1}{2}$.

What is the slope of a tangent line to a curve? That's the derivative, $y'(x) = -e^{-x}$. Where will this slope be $-\frac{1}{2}$? Just solve
$$
-e^{-x} = -\frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
e^{-x} =\frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
e^x = 2
$$
$$
x = \log 2
$$

Okay, let's find the tangent line to that curve at $x=\log 2$.
Firstly $y(\log 2) = e^{-\log 2} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $y'(\log 2) = -e^{-\log 2} = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Thus the tangent line is
$$
L(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}(x-\log2).
$$